# CallBack won't work, please help

Tags: android

Somehow my callback doesn't work...

from a sending activity:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("Constructor.rob.call");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

receiving activity:

```
public class popup extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.popupcanvas);

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Constructor.rob.com.call");
            this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);    
    }


    private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

and from the manifest:

```
...
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="Constructor.rob.com.call" />
</intent-filter> 

</application>
</manifest>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending `"Constructor.rob.call"` but catching `"Constructor.rob.com.call"`